Need help wiring ceiling fan
I live in a 1950s home. I am trying to wire a ceiling fan. The wires coming from the ceiling are black, white, and brown. The wires on the fan are black, white, amd blue. I have tried everything I can think of and nothing works. The switch on the wall has a black and brown wire attached to it if that helps. Any help would be appreciated.



Picture of the switch showing the wires attached to it?

The way the switch is wired will help a lot.  So a pictures will help.  As a guess the black and blue on the fan should be for fan and light/s.  Make and model of the fan will help also.

You need a no-contact voltage tester. The box stores sell them for under $20.
With that you can verify which wire from the switch is the switched hot wire (hot when the switch is on) and which wire might be a constant hot wire that is hot whenever the breaker is on.
The switch is fed constantly hot from the breaker circuit and then the switched hot wire coming back from the switch goes to the light. This will become the power to the fan in this case. If you only have a 2-wire cable coming from the switch then you will need a remote control fan/light to control both the fan and the light unless you don't mind operating the light or the fan with a pull chain on the fan.
The electrical code has required for years that the white wire in the cable going to the switch will become the constant hot and is then re-identified as a hot wire with black tape or other means and the black coming back from the switch to become the switched hot wire.
Many times the means of re-identification has faded or the tape pealed off or the person that did it just did not bother to re-identify the white wire.
For future reference, it is always desirable to take pictures of something BEFORE you take it apart to refer to later as you try to put it back together. This wiring issue is probably the number one problem with homeowners attempting to replace a light with a fan/light combo.
Crip659 is correct that the blue wire should be labeled for the light and the black wire labeled for the fan, and the white wire should be connected to the neutral wire of the system. This needs to be verified if someone has not properly re-identified the wiring to the switch.
Good luck!

The black and the blue on the fan are for the light and fan. Depending on how you want it to operate you can wire them together and then connect them to the wire that was connected to the light fixture you took down. White will go to white since that’s the neutral. You can attach the green to the metal box in the ceiling. You’re going to need to figure out which wire is operated by the switch. You can get a cheap non contact electrical tester from a home improvement store. Once you determine what wire is hot when the switch is on then you’ll wire that to the black/blue from the fan.
